# Unable to run a jsp project in eclipse installed in centos 6

Tags: linux, eclipse, jsp

I have installed eclipse-jee-luna-R-linux-gtk-x86_64 in my centos 6 and also installed tomcat 6.

My problem is that i am not able to run jsp project.when i right click on my project and select run on server a window appears with  disable radio button of choose an existing server

[image]

I have also added Apache Tomcat from window prefrences option in eclipse.
what should i do?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please elaborate more how did you installed Tomcat AS?
Have you added an Eclipse internal Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved a similar problem on a fresh install of Eclipse Luna on CentOS 7.

In my case, the root of the problem of not being able to (a) see an existing server that has been defined in Window -> Preferences -> Server and/or to (b) create a new server from to page you have shown above, was a permission problem that I found when I tried to create a new server from the Webcontent page I wanted to run on the server.

All installation guides I've seen suggest to install Tomcat in `/opt/whatever-your-Tomcat-version-is`. Starting the server usually requires root privileges or defining a group or user combination with appropriate privileges to start/stop Tomcat. If you're logged in as `non-root-user` and try to start Tomcat via Eclipse, your user privileges most likely do not allow you to start Tomcat.

I solved my problem by first copying Tomcat into my workspace and changing the ownership...

```
cp -R /opt/whatever-your-Tomcat-version-is ~/workspace/ 

chown -R your-username:your-username ~/workspace/whatever-your-Tomcat-version-is
```

...and then pointing Eclipse to use that instance of Tomcat. This worked immediately and I was able to start/stop the server and run my test webapp.

Note: You have to make sure that no other Tomcat is running on your system (e.g. if configured to start automatically after boot, e.g. by using `ps -ax | grep tomcat`
), else the Tomcat startup fails because of port conflicts (which can be prevented if you change port definitions in your Tomcat config file).

BTW, one more suggestion: Tomcat 6 is outdated because of the JDK dependencies (1.5) that are no longer supported. I suggest you use the latest Tomcat 7 with JDK 1.7 (not 1.6 as suggested on the Tomcat 7 home page -- as 1.6 is also outdated and longer supported).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't installed any apache server in your machine.

Check [here](http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-tomcat-server-on-centos-rhel/) how to install apache on centOS.

then you will be able to select installed version.

Edited link. i hope this will help you.

Comment: i have installed tomcat6 as i explained in my question. The link you showed me is for Apache httpd Server and not for apache tomcat for java check the link  `http://www.coderanch.com/t/85182/Tomcat/difference-Apache-HTTP-server-Tomcat`

Comment: You have to add server first before you start deploying your application over server; check this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html)

Comment: i had already tryed this tutorial. In my question i clearly said that i have added apache tomcat from window prefrences option in eclipse.